# Add property to a class instance

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's consider the following code:

```
class MyClass{
    x: number;
}

const inst = new MyClass();
inst.x = 8;
inst.y = 9;
inst["z"] = 10;
```

Typescript compiler is complaining about adding `y` property in the instance of `MyClass`. That's not the case with `z` property.

***Is that behaviour based on the fact Typescript tries to keep the same shape for all the instances of a class or something else?***

Actually, I am using Angular and I am getting the above behaviour inside the components when trying to assign a value to a property not previously defined e.g.

```
this.prop = 5;
```

Comment: Yes, that's a known feature: You can read more about the difference of the dot notation and the bracket notation in TS here https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3126-object-access-bracket-notation-vs-dot-notation-with-typescript-in-angular-2-rc-4.htm

Answer (score 3):

Well, the idea of creating classes and using TypeScript is to limit your object properties to the defined ones on it...

inst["z"] works because you're appealing to a vanilla javascript behaviour - what is permitted on TypeScript.

But, if you really need to allow your class to receive new properties, you can change it to:

```
class MyClass {
    [key: string]: any;
    x: number;
}
```